# How to do auto login, store the session in the browser

Tags: php, session-cookies

I have seen some social network sites, if you have a user account, and when you open the browser and type the url, you will be directly loged in without inputting the username and password even if you close the computer and restart the browser your can still be automatically loged in which is different form before which you need to log in with your log in details, I think this is not only include  the session cookie like the following

```
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-2592000, '/');
```

but might be more complicated than it. suppose if I use php, can anybody tell me how to implement this function, I assume it's done on the server side, sorry if I didn't make clear description.

Comment: What about this: http://www.evolt.org/node/60265 ?

Comment: thnaks, that's a good tutorial, is this stackoverflow website did the same thing too? because every time when I log in, it automatically keep me log in all the time even if I restart my computer

Comment: Yup, that's called a cookie. I advise you to read about cookies and sessions if you want to get to know how to manage users in your websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is, I keep user ID and/or username and login hash, md5(userID + username + password) as cookies.

Upon another visit, take ID from cookie and check login hash against the same formula it was generated. If the same, login automatically.

**Global**

```
$randomSeperator = '!~!';
```

**First Run...**

```
$hash = md5($id . $randomSeperator . $username);
setCookie('id', $id);
setCookie('username', $username);
setCookie('hash', $hash);
```

**Second Run...**

```
$id/$username/$hash = $_COOKIE[][][] .... // Get all 3 cookies

if($hash == md5($id . $randomSeperator . $username) ){
// Do Autologin
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but my understanding isn't good, can you show me some specific code so that i could have the whole picture on it, thanks.

Comment: At a glance it seems to me that it is insecure.