# Persist PHP Session after closing browser

Tags: php, asp.net, session, cookies, session-timeout

Bit of a backstory to this one...

I have an ASP.NET Login App on my site and once logged in, I can navigate to the WordPress(PHP) side (still on the same domain) whilst maintaining the session. See my pastie link below for how this works.

However, the **problem arises if I close my browser, I then lose the PHP 'session' despite keeping the ASP.NET session**. So I'm 'logged out' on the PHP side but still 'logged in' on the .NET side.

-- **Is there a way, using my existing code, to set a lifetime to the session/cookie, to avoid the session/cookie disappearing when I close my browser?** --

I have pastie'd my current PHP code from my template's *`<head>`* here: http://pastie.org/private/ndcqgbog34uqld1etozda which checks and persists the session.

I did have a look at [this example on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#100657) but got confused as to how to use it in my solution.

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you should be using `setcookie()` with an expiry time (see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)). You're only setting stuff in the session (copied from cookies, it looks like, but I'm not sure what their lifetime is).

Instead of this line:

```
$_SESSION[DOT_NET_SESSION][ $tuple['SessionName'] ] =
    $tuple['SessionValue'];
```

Try this:

```
$cookie = array($tuple['SessionName'] => $tuple['SessionValue']);
setcookie(DOT_NET_SESSION, $cookie, time() + 60 * 60 * 24);
```

That should set a cookie for a day, I think.

Comment: Good call. Currently I'm just storing the values in a database and using my PHP to check these values exist. Can you show me how best to do this using my existing code?

Comment: I've added an example, but you'll have to bear with me - I do a lot of symfony, so it's been a while since I've touched the underlying cookie/session implementations! `:)`. So, you'll have to play around with it a bit. The trick is to look at your cookie data in your browser (e.g. Firefox) to see if you've got it right.

Comment: Heh, no worries, sir. Many thanks for posting an example. I will give it a try in a sec and report back.

Comment: Afraid this didn't work, halfer :( I still do require the line you replaced to check against the table in my database.

Comment: Well, as I say you may need to hack around with it. Since I'm not sure what things you need to pick up from the .net cookie, just use your usual debugging approach to see if each function gives you what you expect at each juncture. Try my line in _addition_ to your existing code, maybe?

Comment: Cool. I will do. Thanks again for taking the time to look at it. I notice in my FF that a particular cookie exists when I'm logged into the .NET side so I may try use that if no session exists in the PHP. It's set to expire in 2 years :D

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to do.

1. [Set the cookie lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) (it defaults to 0, which PHP interperates as "Until the browser closes")
2. [Configure the session garbage collection lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime).  This determines how long before the server side session data is destroyed.

I'd recommend that you don't do this, though.  Sessions that persist beyond the lifetime of a browser session (which ends when the browser closes) are problematic from a security standpoint

Comment: Hi GordonM. Many thanks first for your instructions and security advice. Can you possibly show me how I achieve the first 2 points using my php code in the pastie? I understand what to do, but really confused how to. Really appreciate any help here.

Comment: You do it in the PHP configuration (php.ini)

Comment: Aaaah excellent. I will try setting them shortly and keep you posted.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work. I added `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',86400);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',1440);` to the top of my script, but it didn't keep me logged in when i restarted the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you must be store some data in cookie of user browser. then if user comming back to your bage you are execute the validation block of your code.

for see the complete solution [How to do auto login, store the session in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961578/how-to-do-auto-login-store-the-session-in-the-browser)